# Rails 3.2: Undefined method 'class_inheritable_accessor' in activemerchant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activemerchant, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm building my first Rails app and trying to integrate [active_paypal_adaptive_payment](https://github.com/jpablobr/active_paypal_adaptive_payment) with Rails 3.2.1, however when I try to boot up the rails server it runs into the problem of, "undefined method 'class_inheritable_accessor' (in line 4 of post_date.rb) in the activemerchant-1.5.1 gem of which is a dependency.

I've looked around and seems this method has been removed in rails 3.2. From what I understand, it's not as simple as going into the activemerchant gem and replacing `class_inheritable_accessor` with `class_attribute` ([read this conversation](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/issues/339)).

Any ideas on how I could update this gem so it could be compatible with Rails 3.2? It's an outstanding issue on the github page so appreciate any help with it!

Answer (score 2):

This particular commit solved my issue: https://github.com/cmezak/active_paypal_adaptive_payment/commit/c6661704c45b73a0be5c608c673b106ac1eb5b69